# chmod unable to set setuid in Solaris 11 with zone

Tags: solaris, setuid

I am using a Solaris cluster with shared storage. I have created a mount point in global-zone using shared storage [let it be `/external/mnt`] and then this mount point is further used in non global-zone. Following is an example which explains how mount points are created:

Below is the output of `df -h` in global zone:

```
/dev/global/dsk/d10s0   60G    5G       55G    92%    /external/mnt
```

Below is the output of `df -h` in non global zone:

```
/external/mnt 60G    5G       55G    92%    /external/mnt
```

Basically what I want is to set SUID [through non global-zone] of some of my executables which are present in `/external/mnt`, but getting following warning:

> ```
> # chmod 04111 [EXECUTABLE_PATH/EXECUTABLE]
> chmod:Warning: can't change [EXECUTABLE_PATH/EXECUTABLE]
> ```

Other permissions could be set through `chmod` in this location. Below is the list of privileges given to non global-zone:

```
root@agcf1b:~# ppriv -l zone  
contract_event  
contract_identity  
contract_observer  
dax_access  
file_chown  
file_chown_self  
file_dac_execute  
file_dac_read  
file_dac_search  
file_dac_write  
file_link_any  
file_owner  
file_read  
file_setid  
file_write  
ipc_dac_read  
ipc_dac_write  
ipc_owner  
net_access  
net_bindmlp  
net_icmpaccess  
net_mac_aware  
net_observability  
net_privaddr  
net_rawaccess  
proc_audit  
proc_chroot  
proc_clock_highres  
proc_exec  
proc_fork  
proc_info  
proc_lock_memory  
proc_owner  
proc_priocntl  
proc_session  
proc_setid  
proc_taskid  
sys_acct  
sys_admin  
sys_audit  
sys_mount  
sys_iptun_config  
sys_flow_config  
sys_ib_info  
sys_ip_config  
sys_nfs  
sys_ppp_config  
sys_resource  
sys_share
```

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  Where is the file system mounted from?  How is it mounted?  What type of file system?  All error message(s).

Comment: hi @AndrewHenle I have added some more information in my question, if possible can you please have a look

Comment: Are you running in a cluster?

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes I am running it in cluster.

Comment: What's the output from `mount`?  I seem to recall the underlying protocol for a shared cluster file system is NFS, which would explain why you can't `chmod` as root squash is probably in effect.